# Adding social authentication to site

Tags: django

Django==1.10.5. i have isntalled - pip install python-social-auth==0.2.12. Then addes social.apps.djang_app.default to the INSTALLED_APP settings. After wanted to sync python-social-auth model with Database

```
python projectname\manage.py migrate
```

But i got an error: AppRegistryNotReady:Apps aren't loaded yet

Answer (score 0):

0.2.12 is outdated and the library itself is [deprecated](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-social-auth/0.3.6).

Consider trying [newer version](https://github.com/python-social-auth) or switching to [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) instead.

Comment: I installed allauth, then migrated. so i got an error: No module named='social-django'

Comment: Remove social-django from the settings.py since you don't need it any more.